# unused B1/B2 for tourism purposes

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas

vMy question is that I issued a b1/b2 visa in 2015 to attend exhibition in USA sponsored by my employer, but I couldn't attend this exhibition due to work load in the company and couldn't go to USA to attend that exhibition.

The primary  objective of this visa was "attending an exhibition", now I wanted to go to USA for tourism purposes on this visa, my questions are:

1-If unused b1/b2 visa not used in first place for the primary purpose(to attend exhibition) it was issued, can be use for tourism purposes?

2- Any issue(s) at POE?

3- By immigration laws is it ok to travel for tourism on this visa

3- which documents to present at POE in case I am going for tourism?

3- In the past I have travel to USA two times first on b1 and then on b2

This b1/b2 visa has no Annotation (Annotation field is blank)

This visa was issued in Pakistan.;

Can I use this b1/b2 visa for tourism purposes?

Is that the myth or rumor that the b1/b2 can be used only for the primary purpose

it was issued? or if b1/b2 not used for primary purpose then can not be use for

further visit?

Hope you will give advice.

Regards,

Noman